# Marginal Density Functions, Piecewise Continuous

Tags: probability, density-function

Let $$ and $$ have the joint density function $(,)=\frac 1{x^2y^2}$. Let $U=4xy$, $v = \frac {2x}y$. Find $f(u,v)$. Find the marginal density of $v$. Your answer should be piecewise defined.

I found $f(u,v) = \frac 2{u^2v}$, which was correct. I'm struggling to find the marginal density of $v$. I integrated $f(u,v)$ in terms of $u$ from 4 to infinity (bounds on $u$) and found $f(v) = \frac 1{2v}$. This was not correct, and not sure how to work with the piecewise part. How to continue?

Comment: What are the bounds in the joint density of $(U,V)$? Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for typesetting math.

Comment: $U \ge 4, \frac 8U \le V \le \frac U2$

Comment: See joint density is meaningless if you do not mention the bounds/support of the variables. This cannot be answered if you do not include the support of $(X,Y)$ in the first place. Please edit to add this info in your post, not in comments.